# How to configure ESLint on WebStorm for multiple projects

Tags: config, webstorm, eslint

I open many projects in my WebStorm at once, each of them can have a different ESLint config.

I would like to configure WebStorm to run the correct ESLint package based on the working file.

Comment: ESLint is a project-specific setting -- you should have no issue configuring different settings for different projects. What problem you are facing exactly? Some details are more than welcome here.

Comment: I open many projects at once

Comment: Here's a feature request on the WebStorm tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25561

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to click shift twice and search for eslint. You can configure your rules for each project there.